# Classes used in a project

Tags: objective-c, class, enumerate

Is there an elegant way to get a list of classes used in a project?

I am aware of `objc_getClassList(...)` which gets all the classes in Objective-C, and I am trying to avoid using `class_conformsToProtocol` to filter out classes.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, you could always look at the list of .m files in the build.

Comment: By "get," do you want to view a list of classes in your project, or do you want an `NSArray` at runtime, containing all of the classes in your project?

Comment: I am aware of the class view which shows the classes in the project. How can I get that using code and without prefixing my classes with anything ? So something like objc_getClassList but only picks up the classes in my project.

Comment: I guess it would be helpful to know why you are trying to do this? Right now it just makes sense to look at Xcode's sidebar? Oh, and welcome to Stack Overflow by the way!

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode, press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to open the symbol navigator and press the `C` icon on the lower left corner to filter by classes.

You can filter even more by pressing the document icon next to the `C` icon. The result will only contain classes defined in your project. Here's a picture with the buttons you have to click marked in red:

[image: Picture of Xcode symbol navigator filtering by classes and project]

Answer (score 1):

This code will search your runtime for every class that starts with the class prefix you specify and return their names (typed but not compiled, beware):

```
NSArray *AllClassNamesInRuntimeWithPrefix(NSString *myClassPrefix) {
    NSMutableArray *retObj = [NSMutableArray array];

    int nClasses = objc_getClassList(NULL, 0);
    if (nClasses > 0) {
        Class allClasses[] = malloc( nClasses * sizeof(Class) );
        nClasses = objc_getClassList(allClasses, nClasses );

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < nClasses; i++) {
            NSString *thisClassName = NSStringFromClass( allClasses[i] );
            if ([thisClassName hasPrefix:myClassPrefix]) {
                [retObj appendObject:thisClassName];
            }
        }
        free( allClasses );
    }
    return [NSArray retObj];
}
```

Searching at runtime for every class *in your project* is a bit of a tall order, since the runtime doesn't have the pattern of a "project," and classes can exist in executables or in frameworks, and can be loaded at any time.

Comment: I am aware of the class view which shows the classes in the project. How can I get that using code and without prefixing my classes with anything ? So something like objc_getClassList but only picks up the classes in my project.

Comment: At runtime you cannot, unless the sorce code is available to your app and you can grep through it. What exactly are you trying to do?